# How to test a method which internally calls public instance method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, xunit.net

I have a method which internally calls public method of same class ,somehow I'm unable to test the method, when I try to mock the public method of class it throws an error. After some research I found that I cannot setup(using moq) the method .

Below is the code method

```cs
public class FaxAsEmailBL : FaxEmailBL
{
    private IEmailSender _emailSender;
    private ILogger _log;

    public FaxAsEmailBL(IEmailSender emailSender, ILogger log)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
        _log = log;
    }

    // This method is a part of interface
    public bool SendFaxAsEmail(FaxMailDTO faxMailDTO) 
    {
        bool isEmailSuccessfully = false;

        // performs some validation, it is fine this method is called.
        bool validationCompleted = CompleteValidation(faxMailDTO);
        if (validationCompleted)
        {
            // performs some logic
            faxMailDTO.FromEmailAddress = AppSettingsHelper.FromEmailAddress;

            // this method returns bool I don't want this method to be actually called,
            // neither i can make it virtual or part of interface
            isEmailSuccessfully = 
                SendEmail(AppSettingsHelper.FaxSMTPServer, faxMailDTO);

            if (isEmailSuccessfully)
            {

            }
        }
        return isEmailSuccessfully;
    }
}
```

Below is my test code

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetFaxAsMailDTO))]
public void SendFaxAsEmailTest_ReturnsTrue(FaxMailDTO faxMailDTO)
{
    string sMTPServerUrl = AppSettingsHelper.RightFaxSMTPServer;

    // this line throws an error System.NotSupportedException:
    // “Unsupported expression: x => x non overridable members"
    _mockNPIFaxAsEmailBL.Setup(x => 
        x.SendEmail(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<FaxMailDTO>())); 

    var result = _nPIFaxAsEmailBL.SendFaxAsEmail(faxMailDTO);
    Assert.True(result);
}
```

Is there any different way to test this method
Thanks!

Comment: Is `SendEmail` part of the `FaxEmailBL` interface?

Comment: @PeterCsala no it is not part of FaxEmailBL

Comment: The thing is that you shouldn't mock your SUT. You should mock the SUT's dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock a method that is part of the class that you are trying to test.

One option is to split the class into different parts, so the `SendEmail` method is part of a interface that is injected as a dependency.

Keep in mind that methods dealing with IO are difficult to unit test. You could perhaps setup a email server that receives emails and can somehow signal to the unit test that it has received the email. But it will be a fair amount of work, and may not be worth the effort. So in many cases it is better to separate out methods like sending emails as much as possible, and minimize the amount of logic they contain. So you can test everything else efficiently.